# Prove that $ \lim_{x \to 0} ((\sqrt{x})( 1 + \sin^2\frac{2\pi}{x})) = 0$

Tags: calculus, limits

I found a solution to $ \lim_{x \to 0} ((\sqrt{x})( 1 + \sin^2\frac{2\pi}{x})) = 0$ that uses exponential functions to solve it, but since the material I am studying does not cover exponential functions till later I am looking for a solution that is perhaps simpler/employs slightly more elementary methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $$0\le\sqrt{x}\bigg(1+\sin^{2}\bigg(\frac{2\pi}{x}\bigg)\bigg)\le2\sqrt{x}$$

Comment: Great, got it. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Isn't there a sqrt(x) missing on the left side?

Comment: Since the right hand side goes to $0$ then the above allows an application of the squeeze theorem. You could also use the inequality you suggest to apply the same idea:
$\sqrt{x}\le\sqrt{x}\bigg(1+\sin^{2}\bigg(\frac{2\pi}{x}\bigg)\bigg)\le2\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your time.

Comment: You're welcome.